# List style image with not function

Tags: css, html, image, list, styles

i try to personalizate my web page with an image on a list. I try to use the list style image but not function.

You can see at the page http://ctp.servizieweb.it/flotta/

I use this code:

CSS

```
/*Lista Flotta */

ul#flotta li
{
list-style-image:url("http://ctp.servizieweb.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/freccia.png"); 
}
```

(I try also to use ../07/freccia.png for url)

MYPAGE

```
<ul id="flotta">
<li>Augusta 109 (06 pax / 300 k/h)</li>
<li>Augusta 206 (04 pax / 240 k/h)</li>
<li>Robinson R44 (03 pax / 200 k/h)</li>
<li>Robinson R22 (01 pax / 180 k/h)</li>
<li>Cessna (10 pax)</li>
<li>Mercedes serie S</li>
</ul>
```

But i can't see the image on the list? Where wrong? Can you help me to know? Thank's

Comment: list-style property should be applied to `ul` or `ol` elements, not `li`s

Comment: linking similar question with different solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911466/unable-to-apply-list-style-image

Answer (score 1):

Your list style images are being hidden because they are being pushed to the left of your container.  Here's what to do to fix this:

First remove `article ul li:before`.  This is pushing everything and adding an unnecessary circle.

Then change this CSS line:

```
article ul li, article ol li {
    line-height: 25px;
    position: relative;
    list-style-image: url('http://ctp.servizieweb.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/freccia.png');
    left: 30px;
}
```

This might not be the EXACT style you're looking for, but this will help you realize where the image is.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a problem with the CSS selector: instead of `ul#flotta il` use `#flotta`. Since `id` is by definition unique, no need to specify what kind of tag it belongs to.  Also there seems to be a problem with the file path--I was unable to find the image when I clicked on the link. In addition, it's customary to place `<style>` tags inside the `<head>` tag of the document, rather than in the `<body>`. Good luck!

Comment: Thank's for the reply. The link is correct, i can see the image.

I use this on a wordpress page and i thik is the unique mode to recall the style on a single page.

Comment: Yes, I can see the image when I copy your link from the question into my URL bar of the browser, but the link from web page code didn't produce anything--in fact I got a 'File not found' error, so perhaps the path on the actual page is mistyped. Did you try changing the CSS selector? And I forgot to mention earlier, `list-style-image` is an attribute that belongs to `<ul>`, not `<li>`.