# Unable to apply list-style-image

Tags: css

I'm not able to apply list-style-image to all the UL lists in this page: http://bit.ly/1nu8rlL

It seems list-style-image:none in another CSS file on the Drupal site is preventing this.

When I developed this page on localhost it worked fine. I've tried all these including inline style to assign image to the list style.

```
#irctc-authorized-agent #irctc-list-2
{
    list-style-image:url(/sites/default/files/tbulletred.png);
}


#irctc-authorized-agent .irctc-list
{
list-style-image:url(/sites/default/files/tbulletred.png);
}

#irctc-authorized-agent ul{
list-style-image:url(/sites/default/files/tbulletred.png);
}
```

**How can I make it work?**

EDIT: Unfortunately even !important isn't working. Though in the "Computed" properties the browser is correctly showing it is assigned to image but still I see same disc in the list as in the Chrome Debugger [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7aEugGV1GwTRmJ4OE1lMFU5YUk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: add !important directive for css property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS should look like this

```
#irctc-authorized-agent #irctc-list-1, 
#irctc-authorized-agent #irctc-list-3,
#irctc-authorized-agent #irctc-list-4,
#irctc-authorized-agent #irctc-list-5 {    
    list-style-image: url(http://www.utilitiesindia.com/sites/default/files/flower-bullet.png);
    }
```

but it's being over-ridden by

```
ul li,
ul.menu li, 
.item-list ul li,
li.leaf {
    padding: 0 0 .2em 1.5em;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-image: none; /* here */ 
    background: transparent url(menu-leaf.gif) no-repeat 1px .35em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. After reading your answer I'm trying to list-style-image for li now but it's giving me image bullet + default disc bullet. How to remove the disc bullet?

Comment: Got it. I'd need to resent li's bg property.