# CSS list-style-image not showing

Tags: html, css, image, list

I'm trying to get an arrow as list style image. Googling and here on SO I found some things that can go wrong (display: list item, overflow, using background image,  but didn't help. The path is correct.

```
ul#contactlist {list-style-image:url('images/images/arrow.png'); list-style-type: square; padding: 15px;}
    ul#contactlist li{display: list-item; padding: 10px; overflow: visible; width:100px; margin: 1px;
```

I also tried

```
ul#contactlist li{background-image:url('images/images/arrow.png'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:0px 0px;
```

And

```
ul#contactlist li{background: url('images/images/arrow.png') left center no-repeat; list-style-position: inside; vertical-align: middle;}
```

What's weird is that the `list-style-type: square;` isn't showing either, but when I put `display: list-item;` on the ul#contactlist, there is 1 square.

`list-style-position: inside;`  or outside, didn't help

This is the HTML.

```
<ul id="contactlist">
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why don't you use pseudo elemnts?

Comment: Are you using any framework? It seems that your `<li>` tags are being set to another value of the `display` property.

Comment: Your code works for me - only changed the image link. http://jsfiddle.net/dvy7y7hv/

Comment: similar question with different fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911466/unable-to-apply-list-style-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work just fine...

I'm guessing some of your other bits of CSS are contradicting / overriding the `list-style-image`, or your image path is incorrect.

```css
#contactlist {
    list-style-image: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7e/Sideways_Arrow_Icon.png/50px-Sideways_Arrow_Icon.png");
}
```

```html
<ul id="contactlist">
    <li>lorem</li>
    <li>ipsum</li>
    <li>dolor</li>
    <li>sit amet</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, other CSS (ul li: list-style:none;) was conflicting. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try below CSS

```
ul#contactlist {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul#contactlist li{
    background:url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-ios7-arrow-forward-16.png') 2px 4px no-repeat; 
    display: list-item;
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 20px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/9douwxeo/)**

Answer (score 2):

You could try this.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
}
ul li:before {
  content: ">"; /* remove this is you want to use the image! */
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  left: -30px;
  background: url("images/images/arrow.png") no-repeat 50% 50% / contain;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
  <li>LIST ITEM</li>
</ul
```